# При нажатии Enter, VSCode переносит точку с запятой в css документе на следующую строку

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, перенос

При нажатии Enter, VSCode переносит точку с запятой в css документе на следующую строку. Как убрать?
Пример.

```
    p {
    font-size: 14px;
    }
```

Выбираю свойство из выпадающего списка, задаю значение, курсор стоит перед точкой с запятой. Нажимаю enter , чтобы набрать следующее свойство, а точка с запятой переносится на следующую строку.
В саблайм не было такой проблемы, точка с запятой не переносилась и можно было быстро переходить к новому свойству

Comment: Можете показать в какой момент он это делает? И почему не должно переносить?

Comment: Отредактировала вопрос. Не должно переносить в целях быстроты написания кода. В саблайм эта точка с запятой как бы не участвует в процессе написания. После enter происходит переход на новую строку, а точка с запятой остаётся на предыдущей строке.